# How to write a function to modify a Char list and return it in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Modification may well be just an addition of 3 to the Char ascii value.
I have gone through several books and can't find a solution off the shelf. 
(Returning the Char list can be to a different list variable.)

Comment: About books, "Learn you a Haskell for Great Good !" (http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#data-char) is a good introduction to Haskell and has an implementation of caesar code (similar to what you want to do).

Comment: Short answer: You can't, Haskell lists are immutable.

Comment: @Landei I think you misinterpreted the intent of the question. There are mutable arrays within certain monads, but the OP didn't mention in-place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import Data.Char
shiftAscii :: String -> String
shiftAscii xs = map (chr.(+3).ord) xs
```

would do what you ask.

It works because `map` edits each character in the string using the supplied function.

`ord` converts the `Char` to its `Int` value
`(+3)` shifts the (ascii) by 3
`chr` converts back to a `Char`,

so `chr.(+3).ord` is those three strung together with function composition `.`

---

To be more flexible, you could write

```
shiftAsciiBy :: Int -> String -> String
shiftAsciiBy n = map (chr.(+ n).ord)
```

notice that shifting the ascii doesn't respect alphabet boundaries, so if you were needing this to do `rot13` encoding or similar simple shift, you'd be better off with a hand-rolled shift function that only edits the alphabet

```
addAscii :: Int -> Char -> Char
addAscii n c | isUpper c = chr $ ((ord c - ord 'A' + n) `mod` 26) + ord 'A'
             | isLower c = chr $ ((ord c - ord 'a' + n) `mod` 26) + ord 'a'
             | otherwise = c
```

for example

```
['A'..'z']
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

and we shift just the alphabet ascii:

```
map (addAscii 5) ['A'..'z']
"FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE[\\]^_`fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde"
```

Comment: just saw a line of map (+3) a --that would do the trick for increasing the Int value too i guess,

Comment: in the line shiftAsciiBy n = map (chr.(+ n).ord) --n appears as both an Int and a String?? ...is this normal?

Comment: @MikSeljamaa map (+3) will only work on numbers. Haskell won't let you use a Char as an Int, so I converted (ord), added ((+3)), then converted back (chr).  Actually  n  doesn't appear as an Int and a String, because in that line there's no String!  map (chr.(+ n).ord)  is a function String -> String. This is OK because in Haskell functions are just data, so if you miss off the last argument, it's a thing that wants another argument, namely a function. It's called partial evaluation: weird at first, but very useful. It might have been clearer to put  shiftAsciiBy n xs = map (chr.(+ n).ord) xs

Comment: got it all sorted first version works ok now, my very first program in Haskell!!!

Comment: @MikSeljamaa Hooray! Congratulations! The more you learn, the more you'll enjoy. Keep going. Well done!